# ZeroMQ C++ epgm pub-sub not working

Tags: c++, udp, zeromq

Here is my code of publisher and subscriber using epgm in zeroMQ, where publisher publishes a string "x." continuously and subscriber should receive the messages but it is not happening in this code.

** publisher code:**

```
include zmq.hpp 
include string 
include unistd.h 
include iostream 
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    void *context = zmq_init(1);

    void *publisher = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);

    zmq_bind(publisher, "epgm://eth0;239.192.1.1:5555");


    string s = "x.";


    while (1)
    {

    zmq_msg_t message;

    zmq_msg_init_size(&message, s.size());

    memcpy(zmq_msg_data(&message), s.c_str(), s.size());


    int rc = zmq_sendmsg(publisher, &message, ZMQ_DONTWAIT);

    }

    sleep(3);

}
```

**Subscriber code:**

```
include zmq.hpp 
include string 
include unistd.h 
include iostream 
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    zmq::context_t context(1);

    zmq::socket_t subscriber(context, ZMQ_SUB);

    string subscription = "x";

    zmq_connect(subscriber, "epgm://eth0;239.192.1.1:5555");

    const char *filter = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "x";

    subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, filter, strlen(filter));

    int ret_val;

    while (1)
    {

    string msg_buffer;

    zmq_msg_t message;

    zmq_msg_init(&message);

    if ((ret_val = zmq_recvmsg(subscriber, &message, ZMQ_DONTWAIT)) < 0)
    {

        cout < "Not receiving";

        cout ret_val;

        sleep(1);

        continue;


    }

    int size = zmq_msg_size(&message);

    msg_buffer.assign((const char *) zmq_msg_data(&message), size);

    cout << "Msg buffer : " << msg_buffer << endl;

    }
    sleep(3);

}
```

**Output:**

```
    Not receiving
    -1

    Not receiving
    -1

    Not receiving
    -1

    Not receiving
    -1

    Not receiving
    -1

    Not receiving
    -1
    Not receiving
    .
    .
    .
```

Please suggest me why is this happening so...and how to solve this ?

Comment: Of note you have not set any rate limits and presumably running on the same host.

Comment: @Steve-o could you elaborate? the default limit is 100kb/s and although ZMQ_MCAST_LOOP is no longer supported (since 3.0) i assumed that when binding to ethernet device (not lo) is should work

Comment: It won't work if you run on the same host, even bind to eth0

Comment: Maybe binding and connecting to _eth0_ is the problem. Note that the support for device names is not supported on every platform. I suggest to check the return codes. Btw., I have a test running on 127.0.0.1, where broadcasting does work (no separate hosts needed).